# GCP AI Notebook create for single user feature is gone

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

Just a few days ago, I can create AI Notebooks with access permission for just one user, and now it's gone. Where did it go?

**UPDATE**

So I tried with a different user account (same project, different user email) and voila it's there again, below:

[image]

But if I try to go back again to my previous user account, it's still gone, so I think since AI Notebook still pretty much in Beta release, these weirdness might be due to them doing some A/B testing of some sort.

[image]

Comment: Did you verified that the instance still exist? try running `sudo service jupyter restart`

Comment: @ChristianGonzalez, I have already removed those AI Notebook instances I made before, so they won't be there anymore. But I was pretty positive that the "Single User Only" feature was there when I was creating the instances. Anyway I have updated the question, and I think the problem is due to Google doing some A/B testing since AI Notebook is still pretty much in Beta release.